# How to parse large xml files on google app engine?

Tags: python, xml, google-app-engine, sax

I have fairly large xml file 1mb in size that i host on s3.
I need to parse that xml file into my app engine datastore entirely.

I have written a simple DOM parser that works fine locally but online it reaches the 30sec error and stops.

I tried lowering the xml parsing by downloading the xml file into a BLOB at first before the parser then parse the xml file from blob. problem is that blobs are limited to 1mb. so it fails.

I have multiple inserts to the datastore which cause it to fail on 30 sec.
i saw somewhere that they recommend using the Mapper class and save some exception where the process stopped but as i am a python n00b i cant figure out how to implement it on a DOM parser or an SAX one (please provide an example?) on how to use it.

i'm pretty much doing a bad thing right now and i parse the xml using php outside the app engine and push the data via HTTP post to the app engine using a proprietary API which works fine but is stupid and makes me maintain two codes.

can you please help me out?

Comment: Sounds like a job for the App Engine bulk loader: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata.html

Comment: How about to parse the XML into several lists/dicts; store them in the memcache without saving them to the datastore; and after this get the from the memcache and put them in the datastore on several different requests?

Comment: Ilian: using memcache for anything you care about losing is a bad idea, but splitting the data into big chunks and storing them, then using taskqueue jobs to break into successively smaller chunks until you're down to individual entities could work well.

Comment: Would DOM compatiblity be a requirement for you?

Comment: at the end what i did is use alot of async tasks and SAX to parse the xml quickly and create alot of tasks for each node. not perfect but works.

Answer (score 0):

For uploading large volumes of data, take a look at the [Uploading and Downloading Data](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata.html) help page.

Comment: Yeah, its not a good usage. i need to map an xml to different entities. its no use for me.